# Ninject injected objects are not the same in web api controller and filter

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, ninject, asp.net-web-api

I am using Ninject to inject dependencies into web api filter

```
public class CookiesAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    [Inject]
    public IServiceClient _serviceClient { get; set; }
........................................................
}
```

Then in controller I inject the same IServiceClient in constructor.
In action I am doing some stuff with this object and after that have some logic in OnActionExecuted method of filter.
The problem is that object in filter is not the same as object in Controller.
During ninject scope disposal I can get from container object which had been changed in Controller, but I don't understand why there is no changes in object being used by filter.
I am using InRequestScope for it.

Comment: Hi Alexander, are you using BindFilter from Ninject.MVC3? It is not clear if this attribute is being created by he container or the MVC pipeline.

Comment: No, I am just trying to use property injection.